# Create and edit Dashboards in Professional Edition

Tags: dashboard

In Professional Edition, I have standard user that is unable to create or edit any dashboards.
I would like to allow selected 'standard' users to be able to create new dashboards and/or edit selected existing ones.  I have taken the required steps to 'share' the key report and dashboards folders but I think the problem is regarding permissions for these users.  But I don't know how to grant the necessary permissions to these users in PE.  Thanks.